# Invalid opus configuration for gstreamer

Tags: plugins, configuration, gstreamer, opus

I'm struggling to figure out how to install opus plugin for gstreamer. I have installed
opus-tools & libopus0 by apt-get (everything happens on Ubuntu 14.04). I have also gstreamer-plugins-bad installed.

After multiple trials, bugs, etc. gstreamer displays the following error each time I try to call gst-inspect-1.0:

***(gst-plugin-scanner:17408): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopus.so': /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopus.so: undefined symbol: opus_multistream_encode***

**What could have gone wrong during opus installation process that could cause this error?**

If it's of any use here's result of **ldd /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/libgstopus.so**

```
*/opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib$ ldd /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/libgstopus.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff859fe000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4f9004f000)
libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 => /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8fe08000)
libgsttag-1.0.so.0 => /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8fbcf000)
libgstrtp-1.0.so.0 => /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/libgstrtp-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8f9b5000)
libgstbase-1.0.so.0 => /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8f75c000)
libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 => /opt/gstreamer-1.4.0/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8f450000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8f1ff000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8eef7000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4f8ecd8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f8e912000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4f8e6f9000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f4f8e4f4000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4f8e2f0000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f4f8e0e7000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f4f8dea9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f90587000)*
```

I must have missed something when installing opus, however i've no more ideas what to do, so I'm counting someone can give me some hint where to look for, or what could have gone wrong?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

your error means that opus library has not been correctly linked into your gstreamer.
Did you install gstreamer-plugins-bad yourself? while doing so, when you run the configuration script from the plugin-bad package, you could add following options:
./configure --host=xxxx **--with-plugin=opus** --prefix=xxxxx